# Yammer Oauth/application confusion

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, yammer

I need to just search Yammer for a various string on the timeline and facing a few weird issues.

Using Nuget, I got the yammer.simpleapi package (Found the bug everyone was talking about and changed it from GET to POST) and I  created an App on Yammer, but, this is where the fun starts.

I have a local page `http://localhost/home/yammer` which redirects to Oauth and then redirects to my app with the key and I retrieve basic user settings.

Now, this is where I get confused - I see if I refresh this page, I just get a blank response (I guess that the code is only good for one query?), but if I refresh the http://localhost/home/yammer - I sometimes get the correct response and sometimes I get nothing.

This is best shown in a recording I did - https://youtu.be/RqrAGiP7Rh4

This is really annoying me and I was wondering if anyone knows what is going on?

I would post code examples, but, there hasn't really been anything modified from the original yammer.simpleapi other than the keys.

Answer (score 0):

The web example app is just working one time.

If you want to replay your page, you should save your YammerClient somewhere (or declare it in static)